# Create an Azure Linux VM with a large os disk?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

Does anyone know how to resize an OS disk on an Azure Ubuntu VM? Currently it's 29.3GB and I'd like to make it larger or create a new VM from a VHD with larger disk?

Please know that I do not, at all, want to simply attach a data disk. I want a 127gb OS disk.

Microsoft says you can create an OS disk up to 1023GB…but all my instances have 29.3gb - 8 core, 56gb of ram - 29.3gb…etc…I do have one system 1 core, 3.5gb that is 127GB OS disk - I have no idea how that happened! lol

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

The basic disk size for linux is 30GB and for windows is 127GB. If you want larger size for the OS disk, you can prepare it at premises (using hyper-v) and then upload the VHD to azure storage using any cloud storage management tools such cloudberry or cloudxplorer or powershell command then start your vm with that VHD.

You could contribute by create VHD and upload it to VM Depot https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index if you not satisfy with the VM Gallery template..

Answer (score 0):

Cloudexplorer will resize an existing disk up to Azure's limit of 1023Gb.